# Complexity of "$j:M\to N$ is an elementary embedding"

Tags: set-theory

Given two sets $M,N$ and an injective mapping $j:M\to N$, what is the complexity of the statement "j is an elementary embedding (with respect to $\in$)"? Bonus points for a definite formula $\phi(j,M,N)$.

Edit:

Really what I'd like to know is: if in $V$, $j$ is an elementary embedding from $M$ to $N$, then what are the minimal requirements of a set $X$ containing $j,M,N$ so that $X$ recognizes that fact. My intuition tells me that $X$ should recognize this as long as it is transitive. But perhaps $X$ must also satisfy some (hopefully finite) fragment of ZF?

Comment: You also need to put the language, I suppose, as a parameter. Or do you mean just the language of $\in$?

Comment: $M$ and $N$ being sets, with an $j$ being an elementary embedding in the language $\in$.

Comment: I mean, this is really just a question of how complicated is the satisfaction relation, $M\models\varphi(x)$.